# Sending object to sql server in ASP.NET MVC4 Architecture

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I am getting an exception on  db.CrimeReports.Add(i);

"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code "

```
     [HttpPost]
     public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase file)
     {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {

             using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
             {


                 //db.LoginData.Add(new LoginData { UserId = 4, Username = "maria", Password ="rahat"});







                 byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                 file.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
                 var i = new CrimeReport { ImageName = "murder", ImageContent = image, Active =false};
                 db.CrimeReports.Add(i);
                 db.SaveChanges(); 




             }




         }

         else
         {

             ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");

         }

     }
```

Here is my CrimeReport class

```
[Table("CrimeReport")]
public class CrimeReport
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public  int  ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageContent { get; set; }
    public string Createdby { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDt { get; set; }
    string Updatedby { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDt { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportDescription ReportDescription { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You should post the `CrimeReport` class.

Comment: Only ImageId ,ImageName , ImageContent and Active can not be null and ImageId is autogenerated

Comment: How about the other properties, are they allowed to be NULL?

Comment: yes they are allowed to be null

Comment: `CreatedDt` isn't allowed to be null and yet you don't set it. Also, could you check the `i` variable and see if the `ImageId` variable is unique (check it in your database).

Comment: But when I was trying to save this object it was giving me an error but when after long time I thought to check my database there was a row of image with ImageId and CreatedDt automatically. All other fields were null.